# Copy index column into new column with text formatting

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on data that has values in index column and I need additional columns for filtering.

Here is an example of my data:

```
                     PERIOD      BUDGET
B156789 MY First     202201      2829,09
B156456 My Second    202203      78,98
B156324 Third        202204      82,98
B156098 Fourth       202207      9292,26
```

I would like to add new column after index with name PROJECT and as an output:

```
                     PROJECT     PERIOD      BUDGET
B156789 MY First     B156789     202201      2829,09
B156456 My Second    B156456     202203      78,98
B156324 Third        B156324     202204      82,98
B156098 Fourth       B156098     202207      9292,26
```

Split should be performed with?:

```
stripped = text.split()[0]
```

For adding new column I have tried below, but in this case index column does not have a name, so following is not working:

```
df = df.eval('PROJECT=B', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
df['PROJECT'] = df.index.str.split().str[0]
```

```
print(df)

                   PERIOD   BUDGET  PROJECT
B156789 MY First   202201  2829,09  B156789
B156456 My Second  202203    78,98  B156456
B156324 Third      202204    82,98  B156324
B156098 Fourth     202207  9292,26  B156098
```

To set it into first column

```py
df.insert(0, 'PROJECT', df.index.str.split().str[0])
```

```
print(df)

                   PROJECT  PERIOD   BUDGET
B156789 MY First   B156789  202201  2829,09
B156456 My Second  B156456  202203    78,98
B156324 Third      B156324  202204    82,98
B156098 Fourth     B156098  202207  9292,26
```